# pinax account types

Tags: django, pinax

What is the best way to add custom account types in Pinax? For example, I want a Free account, and a Premium Account. However, this is not supported by the Pinax models.

Does this mean I have to fork the Pinax project? There must be an easier way. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `pinax.apps.account` app is meant to handle private/system type settings like Language choice, Time Zone setting, etc. for a given user.

What you are talking about would require you build an app for you project. It would likely be specific to your domain as well as the payment provider you are planning on using.

Comment: I just found out I should pbly be using permissions.